# How to resume a game timer from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, timer, static

I'm making a pong game in windows forms and I can't figure out how to unpause after pausing in my gameplay form. After pausing a pause screen form is started and after clicking unpause it unpauses, however, I don't know how to make the timer start again. Please let me know.

Here's my code:
Gameplay form:

```
        if (isPaused)
            Paused();
    }

    private void Paused()
    {
        gameTimer.Stop();
        PausedScreen pausedWindow = new PausedScreen();
        pausedWindow.Show();
        isPaused = false;
    }
```

Pause Screen form:

```
    public PausedScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UnPause(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        //Resume timer
    }

    private void QuitGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Wonder if your variable and function naming is right... `if (isPaused) Paused()`. Your `private void Paused()` should be `private void Pause()` and very likely your `isPaused` variable should be `isPlaying`...

Comment: I'm don't get understand why this would make difference. Maybe I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If you do not want to allow the user to do anything in the game while paused, consider using `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the event "Closed" when your pausedScreen is closed and then restart the timer in this function.

```
gameTimer.Stop();
PausedScreen pausedWindow = new PausedScreen();
pausedWindow.Show();
isPaused = false;
pausedWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(Closed);
```

```
private void Closed(object sender, EventArgs e){
    gametimer.Start();
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm getting errors with private EventHandler Closed(): "CS0108: 'GameScreen.Closed()' hides inherited member 'Form.Closed'. Use te new keyword if hiding was intended." and, "CS0161: 'GameScreen.Closed()': not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Your second error should be fixed with the edit of my answer. But what is "GameScreen"?

Comment: GameScreen is what I referred to as the gameplay form in the question above. Thank you for the solution, it works.